How to upload file to API test
I use playwright to write API integration tests.
I need call an API that uploads the file.
In the project I have a static assets folder:
/static-assets
   - import.xlsx

How do I reference the file so that I can make the API call?
import { request } from '@playwright/test';
const context= request.newContext();
await context.fetch(url, {
  method: 'POST',
  data: ??
});


Using context.fetch bypasses the UI entirely. You don't need Playwright for this. A true E2E playwright test would use something like a file chooser to upload the file. And if you're testing the routes directly, no need for fetch, better to use supertest/Jest. There are certain use cases where it makes sense to manually fetch to help set up a fixture, but generally avoid. Anyway, I digress: you can attach a file with fetch as described in How do I upload a file with the JS fetch API?.

With all due respect, please don't suggest to use the 'right' framework. I'm writing API tests, not UI tests, so the suggested answers does not apply as they assume html input element

Well, that's just the thing: Playwright isn't an appropriate tool for API tests. It's a UI testing tool that calls the API transitively as part of the full stack. So it appears you're using a screwdriver to hammer nails, and defeating the intended purpose of Playwright. Supertest will be faster, syntactically simpler and more lightweight if you're just hitting your API endpoints. As for the link, any fetch call is basically the same, whether it's attached to Playwright context or not is irrelevant.

See the supertest .attach() function, specifically.

I see what you mean with the suggested thread being too HTML-centric. Try this thread which is focused on Node--the search here is "node fetch upload file", although you no longer need to install node-fetch since it's built into node 18+. But for testing this is going to be a lot of extra syntax and hassle to have to deal with versus using supertest, and Playwright is way overkill unless you're automating the UI (clicks, typing, taking screenshots, etc). context is hardly used in PW tests--it's a small utility added on for rare cases.

Playwright docs also have examples of adding files to fetch: https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-apirequestcontext#api-request-context-fetch. context.post is simpler.

playwright allows to read from filesystem so you can use readFileSync from from 'fs';
import { readFileSync } from 'fs';
import { basename } from 'path';

const filePath = 'static-assets/import.xlsx'; //either full path or relative to project dir
const fileName = basename(filePath);
const file = new File([readFileSync(filePath)], fileName);

//in my case I needed multipart form data
const form = new FormData();
form.append('SomeOtherField', 'BlaBla') ;
form.append("File", file);

context.fetch(url, {
  method: 'POST',
  multipart: form,
});

